# Liferay, Search and Security Model

Tags: search, solr, lucene, liferay, liferay-6

Has anyone had any experience of implementing search on Liferay that required (a moderately complex) security model?  How do you deal with the fact that not all of the results you get back from search engine will have permissions to view the content?  Does the built-in search in Liferay already do this?  If yes, how?

Because filtering the potentially thousands of results after they have been returned can be quite expensive.  And if you don't pass all the results through the filter, you don't know how many total results (hits) your search got that you can as a logged in user, 'see'.

Answer (score 1):

I think it first searches from lucene and then checks whether a user has view permission on that. To check the same if you have access to source code see BaseIndexer.search. I am attaching small snippet below to show you how it does it?

```java
PermissionChecker permissionChecker =
                PermissionThreadLocal.getPermissionChecker();

int start = searchContext.getStart();
int end = searchContext.getEnd();

if (isFilterSearch() && (permissionChecker != null)) {
    searchContext.setStart(0);
    searchContext.setEnd(end + INDEX_FILTER_SEARCH_LIMIT);
}

Hits hits = SearchEngineUtil.search(searchContext, fullQuery);

searchContext.setStart(start);
searchContext.setEnd(end);

if (isFilterSearch() && (permissionChecker != null)) {
    hits = filterSearch(hits, permissionChecker, searchContext);
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought.  This is highly inefficient.  What if you have thousands of relevant results.  They will all need to go through this filter before you get the total number of relevant results that current user can actually see.

Comment: Note that paging is not the issue, one can only permission check until one has number of results one needs to show on one page (that sounded poetic!), but to know total relevant results that can be shown, all the results need to pass through this check.  This check I believe is firing off queries into DB as well which makes the situation worse!  There must be another way!